# Cosa significa "un aitante stallone gitano"?

Tags: word-meaning

Ho trovato su una fiaba l'espressione "un aitante stallone gitano".

Un cavallo "gitano" è una specie di cavallo? Se sì, qualcuno conosce un nome scientifico o alternativo?

Comment: Citazione? Fonte?

Comment: "Il mio papà ha una gamba sola" di Francesco Menichella, Giunti Junior, 2016.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Il cavallo gitano è una specie di cavallo detta anche [cavallo andaluso gitano](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andaluso)
di cui puoi trovare altre informazioni [qui](http://www.agraria.org/equini/andaluso.htm).

L'espressione ***aitante stallone gitano*** a cui fai riferimento nella domanda può riferirsi sia all'animale in questione sia, in senso figurato, ad un uomo prestante di origine [gitana](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/gitano/), cioè relativa a zingari stanziati in Spagna ma di origine egiziana.

Comment: Grazie per la risposta, ma qui sono sicuro che si riferisca all'animale, perché la scena è una gara di cavalli e frase è "(lui) scattato alla guida del gruppo su un aitante stallone gitano."

Comment: Ho modificato la risposta in base alle tue precisazioni.

Comment: @abarisone Dubito che una fiaba per bambini adoperi *stallone* in senso figurato… `;-)`

Comment: Condivisibile, ma il titolo della domanda originale chiedeva una cosa e il testo un'altra... Infatti era molto sensato il tuo commento in cui chiedevi di contestualizzare.